# app run in xcode vs downloaded from app store (calendar access)

Tags: ios, calendar, app-store

I have an app that works with the native iPhone Calendar app. I tested it in xcode on my device and I thought everything was working fine, so I uploaded it to the app store. I downloaded the app from the store onto another device and two things seemed to not work:

1. getting a list of the user's calendars
2. adding an event

But then I plugged the second device into xcode to test it, and now it seems to be working fine. What's going on here? Here is my code that requests access to the Calendar:

```
-(void)parseDone
{
    if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        // iOS 6 and later
        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                if (granted)
                {
                    [self _parseDone];
                }
            });

        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self _parseDone];
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens on the device with the app downloaded from the app store? Does it seem to hang forever?

Comment: No. It was a button that wasn't performing any action.

Answer (score 1):

On your testing device, delete both versions (the testing one AND the one downloaded from the appStore). Then redownload your app and try it.
Had complications like yours as well.

Hope I could help ;)